# OpenFOAM: GCE versus AWS EC2 performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, openfoam

We ran OpenFOAM on both, GCE and EC2 and found EC2 to be 30% faster and overall cheaper (due to faster execution times). See attached image for metrics.

We think it's because of mpirun. We get the following warning when running mpirun on GCE: "A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module was unable to find any relevant network interfaces. Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in lower performance."

We don't get this warning when running on EC2 though.

Can someone help?

Just to be clear, we compared instances in GCE Netherlands data center versus EC2 C5 instances in Frankfurt, both based on Intel Skylake.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. OpenMPI is searching the hardware on the nodes for InfiniBand, and, upon failing to find any, falls back to standard interfaces.

We can tell mpirun to never even check for InfiniBand hardware (and there preventing an unsuccessful search) with the inclusion of -mca btl ^openib on the command line.

Specifically, a command that originally was submitted as

```
mpirun -np 3 -hostfile ../mpihosts helloworld
```

should now be

```
mpirun -np 3 -mca btl ^openib -hostfile ../mpihosts helloworld
```

You can also eliminate the warning by setting

```
--mca btl_base_warn_component_unused 0
```

If that works for you, you can put "btl_base_warn_component_used = 0" in $prefix/etc/openmpi-mca-params.conf (i.e., your side-wide configuration).